# Can PayPal REST API payments calculate shipping and taxes?

Tags: api, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have successfully used the PayPal REST API's to create and execute a payment in the sandbox, but even though I have shipping options and tax rates configured, they do not show up for the user. I expected the shipping options and calculated tax to appear before the user "approves" the payment. Is this feature supported via the REST API's, and if so what do I need to pass to make it happen?

Comment: No, shipping & tax calculations don't apply to REST (or any other API-based) integrations.

Comment: So there is no way to have the address associated with PayPal or the credit card during checkout on a PayPal-hosted site to determine if tax is applicable based on the PayPal profile tax settings? That seems silly...

Answer (score 0):

The tax and shipping profiles are only for PayPal Standard transactions (the "Buy Now" buttons). API integrations like the Classic API and REST API are for more advanced integrations and are designed where PayPal returns the shipping address selected to you and your system chooses the tax rate and shipping rates before the customer confirms payment.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal shipping calculator only applies to Website Payments Standard transactions.
Express Checkout transactions will not use the shipping calculator.
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Using-PayPal-s-shipping-calculator-with-Express-Checkout/td-p/328404

Answer (score 0):

This is related but doesn't answer the question fully I'm afraid.

I've just started looking into applying different state taxes using the PayPal REST API. The `override_charge_models` option when creating a new `BillingAgreement` looks hopeful. It allows you to apply a custom tax amount when creating an agreement.